# Can I create custom keyboard in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uikeyboard

Is it allowed to create a custom keyboard. Will apple approve my app if I used my own keyboard instead of using default one. howsoever I don't have button images, I guess I need to use same default keyboard images do so. Is there any image repository where I can get exact keypad button icon.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPad Human Interface Guidelines that iPhone OS 3.2 supports keyboard customization  http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadHIG/UIElements/UIElements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009446-CH6-SW7

Answer (score 1):

They will almost undoubtedly reject your app.

Comment: Any link or document where I can take reference. Thanks

Comment: Well its not. Even i want to lift a keyboard little above tabbbar. But apple suspects this action and rejects it. Telling that default behavior of iOS application cannot be changed with the help of customizing keyboard. If you are succedding with it, Please let me know.