# Will my application be rejected by Apple if I add a custom keyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, custom-controls, uikeyboard

Per my requirements I need to add a [custom keypad](http://b.imagehost.org/download/0994/keypad).  However, I found out that if there is custom keypad in app that this will be rejected by Apple.  I found code for custom keypad that could be used, but I would like clarification if this is true.  Is it recommended that I add my own custom keypad to my app?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610542/custom-iphone-keyboard, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421462/can-i-create-custom-keyboard-in-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a custom keypad in your app if it is not generated by manipulating the existing keyboard. So if you build it yourself this should be ok.
I have a custom keyboard in one of my apps. No problems with apple.